# TeamCity Mercurial Clone Error

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

When running a Team City Configuration it includes a white space

```
[Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent:'hg clone -U --uncompressed http://_VcsAccess:******@xxxx.com/hg/repo/ 7eaf0d18c3c2de83' command failed.
```

Any clues why tc is including a white space. I tried testing the vcs root and it works...

Comment: What space do you mean? Space between repository url and the revision? Also logs should contain more info on the reason of the failure, can you provide them?

Comment: Nevermind. Mercurial client was no installed on the target agent :S

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial was not installed on the target machine